# Is there any event that triggers right after the layout is applied in Roassal?

Tags: moose-technology

I would like to define animations right after applying the layout. This is important when the visualization is defined within the context of a Glamour browser.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Mondrian DSL, you can use:

view nodes: (1 to: 20).
view horizontalLineLayout 
    on: ROLayoutEnd do: [:event | ... ].

Using the Roassal API, you can use:
ROHorizontalLineLayout
    on: ROLayoutEvent do: [ :event | events add: event ];
    applyOn: yourElements